# My tor browsers closes seconds after opening

Tags: help

Every single time I try to open tor it almost immedietly closes. This happens every single time. I am on a mac.

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or anti-malware software? If so, you probably need to white list Tor Browser in that software.

Comment: I'm using a VPN, but thats it.